# Do new CR users who are trusted elsewhere on SE go through the First Post Queue?

Tags: support, answers, review, new-users

This question is in regards to users who have 100 rep points. When we come here from another SE site, we are awarded 100 rep points to get us started.

What I'm wondering is, do those users go through the first post queue? It wasn't covered in the [First Post FAQ](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1946/first-post-review-queue-what-is-it).

If they do go through the queue, I'd like to remind everyone to not let answers like this through without helping out new users.

Answer (score 10):

Short answer: Yes, they go through the first post queue. I have seen many posts there where the poster has 101 reputation.

Your first post, in fact, was [reviewed here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/20712)