# Why did I receive this moderator message?

Tags: support, review, moderators, review-queue

I got a moderator message informing me that I've made some bad reviews.

However, I failed to see which ones they are pointing at.

Can you please show me? [I've made 21 reviews](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/229550/chocolate?tab=activity&sort=reviews) in total.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that for 13 of the 21 reviews have resulted with <kbd>**No Action Needed**</kbd>  being selected.

[image: screenshot of reviews]

I didn't know this either until a moderator pointed it to me in a private chat room: there is a [Meta answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1947/120114) that explains why such action is frowned upon.

I know that if the community feels strongly about this then perhaps we should find ways to put this in front of people before they get into that review queue, though that would likely involve requesting SE add a feature (which would involve determining how to update the UI) that may or may not be useful on other SE sites.

Comment: There has been some changes around review-bans that could help with this, but I personally would prefer not review-banning someone just to get a message to them :)

Comment: I’m envisioning a preliminary step before users can access the first review queue (once the “access to review queues” privilege is awarded) rather than a ban

Comment: @Vogel612 Currently [the Review Queues are being revamped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351117). Might it be worth providing some feedback about this? A 0 second suspension might be a good solution.

Comment: Noted - I started "following" that MSE post and as subsequent posts are linked I can provide feedback there - e.g. for #3 _New reviewer onboarding for all queues_

Comment: Samuel (among others) has been fighting with the team about this queue for a while now, I think we can mostly wait.